# Login Form in HTML

Tags: php, html, css, form, authentication

I am a beginner and I have made Login Form in HTML. I'm pretty sure it will look horrible to any developer, but hey, that's why I've posted it.

I'd like a general review of this. I'm especially concerned about the quality and enhancements of this form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
/* Basics */
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
#container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 340px;
    height: 280px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -140px;
    margin-left: -170px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);

}
form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
label {
    color: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
p a {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -13px;
    margin-right: 20px;
 -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}
p a:hover {
    color: #555;
}
input {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline: none;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=password] ,input[type=time]{
    color: #777;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #c7d0d2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    }
input[type=text]:hover,
input[type=password]:hover,input[type=time]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #b6bfc0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .7), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus,input[type=time]:focus {
    border: 1px solid #a8c9e4;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #e6f2f9;
}
#lower {
    background: #ecf2f5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 69px;
    margin-top: 20px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.check {
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
input[type=submit] {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #acd6ef; /*IE fallback*/
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#acd6ef), to(#6ec2e8));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #66add6;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b6e2ff), to(#6ec2e8));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
}
input[type=submit]:active {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6ec2e8), to(#b6e2ff));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
    <div id="container">
        <form action="login_process.php" method="post">
            <label for="loginmsg" style="color:hsla(0,100%,50%,0.5); font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;"><?php  echo @$_GET['msg'];?></label>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <div id="lower">
                <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </div><!--/ lower-->
        </form>
    </div><!--/ container-->
    <!-- End Page Content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since username and password fields are mandatory so you can mark these fields as required.  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>

Comment: I don't think the `required` attribute is a thing in XHTML.

Comment: Great Question!

Comment: @ThomWiggers HTML 5 supports this attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: @Sandeep I know, but he's using XHTML.

Comment: My bad..I didn't notice that..

Comment: As @paul [mentioned](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47782/41042) below: Use HTML5. This means use `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of what you have right now in your `doctype` declaration. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Comment: Note that `required` could be removed

Comment: Don't all `<input>` tags need to be closed? Like `<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>` ?

Comment: @SNag depends on the doctype he is using. For the current doctype, this is valid. If she switches to HTML5 then yes, you are correct.

Comment: @stackErr: Thanks! I wasn't aware of validity dependency on doctype. Good to know!

Answer (score 18):

This is one of those places where if you ask 10 developers the same question, you will get at least 15 answers, and they are all valid.

My 2 cents:

- It's 2014. Use HTML5.
- Discover [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this kind of thing.
- Put "required" on the username and password fields, it's free validation.
- There's nothing wrong with in-page CSS. I often mix sitewide and in-page as needed. For the purpose of this example, it works just fine. (This does NOT mean ignore CSS classes)
- Instead of `echo @$_GET['msg']` (and resulting security issues) try `echo $messages[$_GET['msg']]` where `$_GET['msg']` is a number. Define your messages server-side.
- Learn this pattern for unset variables: the ternary operator.

  ```
  echo !empty($_GET['msg']) ? $messages[$_GET['msg']] : '' ;
  ```
- The login message does not need a label (but it's not "wrong" to have it). incorporate the HTML in the stored message for cleaner output when there is no message
- Your checkbox needs both a `name=` and `value=`

Comment: two questions: 1) what is the specific advantage(s) of HTML5 (in this case)? 2) Why not echo empty($_GET['msg']) ? '' : $messages[$_GET['msg']]; (without the negation)?

Comment: @ whoever edited my answer: it's simply "required", not class="required".

Comment: @Rolazaro Azeveires: HTML5 does everything XHTML does, and more. Do you still use Windows 2000 or OSX Panther? Both were great in their day.

Comment: @Rolazaro Azeveires: There's absolutely nothing wrong with empty($_GET['msg']) ? '' : $messages[$_GET['msg']]; That's just part of the "... 15 answers, and they are all valid"

Comment: +99 for that reference about Win2K and OSX Panther. LOL.

Comment: @paul: Do you update just because? For no reason?

Answer (score 14):

Security-wise, you need to make sure you a) never trust the user and b) never trust the user.

You should realise that anyone has access to the `GET` parameters, lines like

```
<?php  echo @$_GET['msg'];?>
```

should thus be avoided. Always call `htmlspecialchars()` on stuff you get from users etc when printing output. Otherwise I could craft an URL like `http://yourwebsite/form.php?msg=<script>alert("lololol");</script>` and inject arbitrary javascript on your webpages. It's quite easy to trick someone into clicking such a link, making them run my code in their session.

People often find using error suppression (`@`) bad style, by the way. It's also quite slow.

Also, you need to make sure your form isn't vulnerable to [CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29). Protecting against this is usually done by adding a one-time, per request randomly generated token to your form. This topic is too big to cover here, so I'd ask Google. [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/) is generally a great resource for website security.

HTML-wise, you should pay attention that you are writing XHTML, going by your `DOCTYPE`. That means you should take care to write valid XML. In XML you need to close every tag. You also need to close tags which only have an 'open' tag, like `<img>`, `<br>` and `<input>`. This is done by adding a forward slash (`/`) before the closing `>`. So `<input>` needs to be `<input />` in XHTML.

If you want your form fields to actually submit results, make sure that they all have a `name` attribute. The checkbox currently doesn't.

Lastly you're using `<label>` tags quite nicely. You should however note that `for` needs to reference an `id` of an `<input>` tag, so the `<label>` for the checkbox doesn' reference the correct field.

I'm not quite a CSS wizard so I'll leave that up to someone else, but it looks pretty decent.

Overall, once you fix these minor bugs, it's a better form than many I've seen in the wild :)

Comment: `htmlentities()` is overkill for most purposes, `htmlspecialchars()` gets the job done well.

Comment: @bjb568 I always forget which one to use :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an expert on HTML, but I am quite decent in using it and can give you the following pieces of advice:

1. Seperate the CSS from your HTML page, it is already good that you have seperated (most) CSS of the HTML elements, but you want to use an *external style sheet*, and include that in your page. This makes both parts more clear (tip: Do try to not mix programming languages) and allows you to reuse the stylesheet on multiple pages easily.
2. Use `class` tags where they are applicable. The `class` tags can be reused and should be used multiple times generally, while the `id` tags are for unique elements. This means that `<div id="container">` and `<div id="lower">` should be a `class`, and not an `id`.
3. Do not secretly sneak in some CSS in your HTML tags. You did it with your `loginmsg` label, you should give it an `id` field and reference that in your stylesheet.
4. I would refrain from suppressing warning messages (the `@`) in PHP, they are usually there for a reason.
5. You are (appereantly) sending the `msg`, which should appear in the `loginmsg` label, as a *GET* argument, thus you are receiving user input. In this case it is one that could easily be tampered with, *POST* arguments can also get tampered, but that is slightly more difficult.
   You should validate your input there, malicious attackers can try to inject javascript code into it, that will redirect someone to another (evil) page, as one of the examples.

This is by no means a complete review, but it are all the points that I have spotted.

Answer (score 5):

I'll only mention items not already addressed in other answers. Viewing the form in Firefox, I see this:[image]

I've circled the odd extra space before the `Username:` label and drawn an arrow to show the missing bottom of the box.

1. The extra space is what the user will see in the case that your PHP script doesn't return a message.  One way to handle that would be to simply insert a `<br/>` tag between the two labels.
2. The missing bottom of the box is due to the way you've sized the `container` in your CSS. It's a wee bit short.

Comment: Actually, `<label for="loginmsg">` shouldn't be a `label` at all, as there is no corresponding `<input id="loginmsg">` form element. Furthermore, it should not be emitted at all if there is no message to display.

Answer (score 1):

I got width scroll bar window in my browser:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I am getting unnecessary scroll bars. Width and height are not needed, so please simply remove them from your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing:

Wrap your checkbox within it's label, so that both the box and the "Keep me logged in" text are clickable and will de/activate the check. It's not essential, but it's good UX.

```
<div id="lower">
    <label class="check" for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"> Keep me logged in</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of wrapping the input in label, you could simply add an `id` for the input that matches the label's `for`.

`<label class="check" for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>`

Comment: Also, when wrapping an input *inside* a label, the `for` attribute can be omitted; use `for` only if you *don't* wrap the input inside a label. Both approaches are right (wrapping or `for`), just pick whatever fits your need.